# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am getting a "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable.

Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
def f(x,t):
    return (exp(-(x-3*t)**2) )*sin(3*pi(x-t))

 x = linspace(-4, 4, 8) 

 y = zeros(len(x)) 

for i in xrange(len(x)):
    y[i] = f(x[i],0)

plot(x, y)
show()
```

Comment: What language is this?  Which line does the error refer to?

Comment: @ScottHunter This is Python.

Comment: Please correct your indentation and provide the _full_ error message -- including the line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pi isn't a function, but since you didn't use * to indicate you want to multiply with it, it looks like you are using it as one.

Answer (score 0):

`float` is a number type in Python. You cannot call this because it is not a function. I am not familiar with the mathplotlib.pylab package, but taking a quick look at your code, I would guess that the error is in this part of the code

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
def f(x,t):
    return (exp(-(x-3*t)**2) )*sin(3*pi(x-t)) #<---- pi is not a function, it can't be called

 x = linspace(-4, 4, 8) 

 y = zeros(len(x)) 

for i in xrange(len(x)):
    y[i] = f(x[i],0)

plot(x, y)
show()
```

If you have not defined a method called `pi` or mathplotlib.pylab contains no method called `pi`, then that would be where your error is. If py is a floating point variable equal to `3.1415` then calling `pi(x-t)` would be the same as calling `3.1415(x-t)`.

You most likely want to perform an operation with `pi`. If so, then use the desired operation. example, `pi+(x-t)

Answer (score -1):

```
c=(1/((abs(r1-rmed)+1)(abs(r2-rmed)+1)))
```

when I type this line in my program, I get the error:

> float object is not callable.

for removing the error I use * between the bracket.

```
c=(1/((abs(r1-rmed)+1)*(abs(r2-rmed)+1)))
```